# Bookdown CSS for custom theorem environment numbering

Tags: css, r-markdown, bookdown

How does one implement a custom theorem environment for HTML output in bookdown that is numbered as "chapter.occurence"? For example, I have defined a "convention" environment.

I placed the following in `preamble.tex`

```tex
\newtheorem{convention}{Convention}[chapter]
```

and in `style.css`

```css
.convention {
    position: relative;
    font-style: italic;
}
.convention p{
    display: inline;
}

.convention:before {
  counter-increment: convention;
  content: "Convention: " "." counter(convention) " (" attr(name) ").";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
div.convention {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

If I provide my second convention in chapter one (file `01-vectors-and-matrices.Rmd`) as

```r
::: {.convention #something name="Something" data-latex=""}
Something.
:::
```

then the LaTeX output works as expected. The HTML output, however, does not produce the expected result. With the HTML (GitBook) output, I have the following issues:

1. `counter(convention)` in the CSS does not appear to count the number of convention environments in the chapter, and
2. I don't know how to refer to the chapter number in CSS.

Both problems reflect my inexperience with CSS. Ideally, I would copy the style of the standard theorem environments (e.g. definition, corollary, remark). But I cannot find the CSS that defines these environments' styles.